# What explains habitual or even occasional incidences of self-talk?

Tags: social-psychology

What are the scientific reasons behind someone talking with him/herself? Is it a disorder of some kind? By "talking" I also mean writing to self.

By self-talk I mean a person (P) is talking with self in a Q&A format. For example-

```
PQ: Hey, what happened?

PA: I'm not liking it here.

PQ: Why, what is it that you are not liking it?

PA: I don't like the attitudes of people around here. Everyone thinks he's very smart ...

PQ: But why is it affecting you?
```

and so on ..

The above kind of dialogue can either be **spoken** or **written**. Usually, one party asks another about their problems/feelings and suggests solutions / gives instructions to other party.

Comment: I think you will need to more clearly define "self-talk" in order to have an answerable question. Do you mean talking out aloud or also internal thoughts? At one extreme, the entire internal monologue could be seen as self-talk.

Comment: I mean the kind of self-talk where the terms like 'you' and 'me' are used. I edited the question a bit.

Comment: reminds me of the [Dialogical Self](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogical_self).  Not sure about the neurobiology off the top of my head but my gut is screaming Wernicke's and Broca's areas.

Comment: Also, do they do it consciously and intentionally, or not? For example, if I am alone and bored or working and bored, I often mutter to myself. But I do it to amuse myself, I don't *actually* think I'm two different people.

Comment: I would think that this is just a generalized form of internal dialogue.  Don't you debate with yourself on what kind of breakfast you would want in the morning?  I mean, this kind of back and forth is how you make any basic pro-con list.